# ERROR ITMS-90163 with compiling with Flash IDE CS6

Tags: testflight, ipa, flash-ide

I made an app using flash ide cs6, and when I want to upload to new testflight I get this error:

ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitltements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'beta-reports-active' in 'Payload/xxxx.app./xxxx'

I already tried with adHoc profile, develop profile, distribution profile, and nothing.. i still have this error..

Any recommendation ?
Thanks

Comment: Are these new provisioning profiles or old ones? The error states that the 'beta-reports-active' key is missing from the profile file - this key is required for TestFlight testing and it's missing from provisioning profile files generated before early this year or something, should be added automatically to newer profiles.

Comment: is a new profile, I revoked all the certificates and build new profiles from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find CFBundleExecutable key , remove this key from info.plist. You can delete all other CFBundleExecutable if error occurs on multiple bundles.

add key:`Bundle identifier` in info.plist.

FORM:[ITMS-90535 Unable to publish iOS app with latest Google Signin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk/32645052#32645052)