# ITMS-90535 Unable to publish iOS app with latest Google Signin SDK

Tags: ios, xcode7, google-signin

[image: Error ITMS-90535 : Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key Google Sigin]

I'm using xcode 7 GM seed and installed latest Google Signin SDK through cocoapods `pod "Google/SignIn` .  I get the attached error when I try to publish my app to apple app store.

Help!!

Here are the detailed versions of Google SDK pods

`- Google/Core (1.0.7):
 - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.0)
 - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
 - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.0)
 - Google/SignIn (1.0.7):
 - Google/Core
 - GoogleSignIn (~> 2.0)
 - GoogleAppUtilities (1.0.0):
 - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
 - GoogleAuthUtilities (1.0.1):
 - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.0)
 - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
 - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0):
 - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
 - GoogleSignIn (2.2.0):
 - GoogleAppUtilities (~> 1)
 - GoogleAuthUtilities (~> 1)
 - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1)`

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also having a similar problem, but with iZettleSDK

Comment: Hey, Google, please fix it ASAP!

Comment: I got the same issue and it solved as the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63284003/8203825)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Find `CFBundleExecutable` key , remove this key from Google Signin SDK's info.plist.
You can delete all other `CFBundleExecutable` if error occurs on multiple bundles

Comment: This is exactly what I did (in Info.plist inside iZettleStorePurchase.bundle and iZettleShared.bundle). After that, I submitted my app successfully.

Comment: I'll accept it as an answer, even though this is more like a workaround than an actual fix.  I hope Google updates their next release to mitigate this issue.

Comment: When I did this it was successfully uploaded but ultimately rejected with the following error: Invalid Bundle - Info.plist of “CollectableApp.app/GoogleSignIn.bundle” specifies a non-existent file for the CFBundleExecutable key...

Comment: app store approved app or reject ? @Eddie

Comment: I had this error with ShareKit. Just searched for "CFBundleExecutable" which helped me out finding it. Hitting the delete made id. Thank you!

Comment: what the side effects of this are?

Comment: Has anybody reported this issue upstream?

Comment: latest cocoapods, plist files dont have these executable file entry. what should I do

Comment: I got the same issue and solved using the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63284003/8203825

Answer (score 24):

Just to clarify the above correct answer.  If you are accessing the info.plist from Xcode, you need to clear the `Executable file` field shown below.

[image]

There is one in the GoogleSignIn/Resources folder, and the other two are in GPPCore/Resources folder.  (click the .bundle)

Answer (score 9):

I had to do this:

Delete 3 string values of 3 lines. 
info.plist from

1.GooglePlus.bunde -> Inside

2.GPPCommonSharedResources

3.GPPShareboxSharedResources

[image]
[image]

[image: Open GooglePlus.bundle]
[image]

Comment: Additional comment. I needed delete the record, not only the string value.

Answer (score 3):

I am getting the same error with TapJoy Bundle Resources.

[image]

TapJoy is older version. So this problem is going to be fixed by either:

1. Update TapJoy SDK
2. Remove the string from **Executable file** of TapJoy's plist, not the app's plist just like user dstudeba suggested. In my case the String was **TapJoyResources** I removed that and worked perfect!

Note: that plist was located at TapJoy's framework files. This error is exactly the same as with this Google Signin SDK issue.

Here's what I did in detail: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have suffered from same [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk), above all answers really helped me.
Want to share my experience.

**1- I was getting the error**
[image]

Fixed with the help of above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32645052/2114413)

> Find CFBundleExecutable key , remove this key from Google Signin SDK's info.plist. You can delete all other CFBundleExecutable if error occurs on multiple bundles

2- But after that, I was getting error

> Xcode App Submisson ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle

[image]

Fixed with the help of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33435595/2114413)

> Please check your info.plist file and add below key if not

`<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>`

Comment: You are tryin to add ? how that is helpful. when there is no binary

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue while uploading our build from jenkins slave. We managed to automate the process by adding this runs-script to pre-archive of our appstore scheme:

```
defaults delete "${PODS_ROOT}/google-plus-ios-sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources.bundle/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable

defaults delete "${PODS_ROOT}/google-plus-ios-sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable

defaults delete "${PODS_ROOT}/google-plus-ios-sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1/GooglePlus.bundle/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable
```