# Can't upload project with google maps sdk to itunes connect. Xcode 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an app that I've rebuilt using Xcode 7. This app has been using the GoogleMaps IOS SDK.

My error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1DOC.png)

My podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

I tried to remove CFBundleSupported platform from google maps.bundle

```
    # Patch GoogleMaps' bundle to avoid iTunes connect submission error
post_install do |installer|
    `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :CFBundleSupportedPlatforms" ./Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle/Info.plist`
    `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :CFBundleSupportedPlatforms" ./Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/Info.plist`
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ITMS-90535 Unable to publish iOS app with latest Google Signin SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk)

Comment: @NSDeveloper i used google maps, not google signin and plist in new version of google maps sdk don't have CGBundleSupportedPlaforms key

Answer (score 1):

This bug is Fixed in Google Maps SDK for iOS 1.10.2.

Try `pod update` and re-submit to iTunes Connect.

Comment: i tried this too. And terminal say that my google maps sdk version is 1.10.3 
https://pp.vk.me/c625717/v625717769/495f1/r931zkyuWXE.jpg. But submit to iTunes Connect doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest Google Maps SDK for iOS 1.10.3

You can read the release notes: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8568