# ERROR ITMS-90535: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. Google Plus and Play Games Xamarin Component

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-play-services

I've been using the Google Plus and Play Games Xamarin Component [(link)](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplusandplayios) in the iOS version of my cross-platform app. I haven't had any trouble uploading it to the store in the past, but after upgrading to Xcode7, I receive the following error when trying to submit my .ipa through Application Loader:

> ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/Brushfire.iOS.app/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."

Since this is a Xamarin Component, I don't believe I have access to the plist file to change this value, so I can't use the solution posed in [ITMS-90535 Unable to publish iOS app with latest Google Signin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk). I don't want to have to wait for an update to the component from Xamarin. Are there any workarounds that could help me get my app into the store?

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin is currently working on a solution to this issue, though we do not have an exact ETA currently on when the component will be out.

I can be sure to let you know on this thread when the updated version is released.

You can also follow along on our forums here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50817/google-maps-for-ios-component-update#latest

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the component I'm having issues with. The component I'm using can be found here https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplusandplayios

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying! The same root cause may be at "play" (its late, I think that is funny). Do you mind filing a bug on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com and I will make sure it gets looked at by  the team. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Update to Xcode 7.1 Xcode

Step 2: deleted (Info.plist file, such as a third-party static library included) App excess Info.plist

Step 3: Remove third-party App resource package Info.plist (Uniform Resource Check App in .bundle package inside if there Info.plist, consider deleting or delete items inside CFBundleVersion and CFBundleIdentifier)