# Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key solution explanation

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode7

I encountered the issue Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key similar to [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key?rq=1) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk?lq=1).

The solution is to remove the info.plist file or edit CFBundleExecutable key of the third party library. 
How safe is it to remove / edit this? Would there be side effects?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?