# Invalid Bundle Info.plist specifies a non-existent file for the CFBundleExecutable key

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, plist

I've updated to Xcode 7 and running into the following issue when trying to archive and send an update to my app to itunes connect.

```
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery.
To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
Invalid Bundle - Info.plist specifies a non-existent file for the CFBundleExecutable key. 
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
```

I've tried to removing the CFBundleExecutable but then I can't build the target. This relates to some google signing sdk issue and isn't my problem.
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32645052/1329173

The only other thing I can find is https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/442 but again this isn't a libray I'm using.

In iTunesConnect it shows me the upload is still in "processing" state and will not get avaible due to issue.
I've also tried cleaning and removing debug and bin folders.

The CFBundleExecutable is set to Executetable_name

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work not knowing what exactly coursed it. I update OS X from Yosemite to El Capitan (10.11). Then Xcode had some components to update when launching, which it didn't specified, it's still Xcode version 7.0.1 (7A11001). The last thing that had changed was iTunes Connect interface (sep-oct 2015), so they could have had some maintenance/update that messed something up as it was labeled as "processing" in iTunes Connect. [Processing for a week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013502/1329173)

Answer (score 6):

Do you have any **.bundle** included in your project ?

If you do, check its content, and make sure it doesn't contain any **plist**, and this plist doesn't contain `CFBundleExecutable` key.
(a broad search for `CFBundleExecutable` in your workspace might give you hint at where this problem comes from...)

In my case, simply removing the whole *Instabug.bundle* did the trick, although you might want to use such a third party, so you might edit the plist instead to remove this problematic key...

Comment: Haven't got any .bundle included no. I only have CFBundleExecutable in the targets .plist. The issue got resolved when I updated the system as my answer describe.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue after updating to Xcode 8: "Info.plist of “*.app/FPKReaderBundle.bundle” specifies a non-existent file for the CFBundleExecutable key". This message came from the FastPDFKit. Removing the entry from the plist helped, thought i have no idea why there is a problem with that!?