# Getting "Cannot verify client. (3000)" when trying to upload archive from Xcode to itunesConnect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Just updated to Xcode 7.1 and getting this error.
Was able to upload fine using 7.0.1

Comment: Without restarting Xcode 7.1, *Clean* and *Clean Build Folder* helped.

Comment: FYI I filed this radar a while back: http://openradar.me/22999921, but Apple has not said anything about it even though I've reached a couple developer relations a few times.

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by a network glitch or a hiccup on the Apple servers that process the uploaded app. It would be nice if Apple could detect this and return a proper error message saying to try again. That would prevent developers from jumping through all kinds of hoops trying to figure out what went wrong like cleaning, rebuilding, using application loader instead, or my personal favorite, disconnecting your wireless mouse. When simply trying again would most likely work.

Comment: Looks like Apple may have fixed it! For the last few months, I've steadily been getting rep from this question and answer - every day. As of 3 days ago, that pattern has stopped.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Hmmm, well a restart of Xcode, a fresh clean, build and archive seems to have fixed it.

Comment: correct. Also, simply uploading the archive again without any changes also often does the trick.

Comment: Trying to upload again, I'd just get the same error. Only after doing the above did the error go away

Comment: @Wizfinger's simple approach (which reminds me of the typical method for troubleshooting old-school Windows issues) did the trick for me.

Comment: Just try it again. If you'd like any magic just tell these words loudly: harevithum haravithos, then try it again. It's working :)

Comment: when i followed these instructions i got a "You are not authorised to use this service iTunes app upload error". i then removed and added my apple id, and then it worked

Comment: Didn't work from first attempt, but worked from 4th or something. Should display an error with 'Xcode screwed up, just try again' instead of other misleading info.

Answer (score 61):

If you encounter this error, you have two options:

*Option A - Engage in an activity that takes a minute or two. Could be any of the activities described in the other answers, like re-install XCode, renew certificates, do a new build from scratch after clearing caches. Or simply go get a coffee.*

**or**

*Option B - Do nothing at all for a little while.*

Then, try again. If it doesn't work, repeat.

Comment: It would be nice if there were at least some hint as to why simply waiting and doing nothing else is the right answer.  Granted, Clean/Rebuild/Restart is a bit of a magical fix - as in there is no good reason it should fix problems but it sometimes does nonetheless - but if you know what is happening it would make this answer better.

Answer (score 12):

> Just updated to Xcode 7.1 and getting this error. Was able to upload
>   fine using 7.0.1

same here - restart, clean build, archive and upload was successful.

Answer (score 10):

Same problem here. Grabbing a cup of ☕️ worked for me.

Comment: I was skeptical at this solution at first, but after 20 minutes of trying to clean build forder, re-archiving, restarting computer and the like, I decided to make some coffee. It worked right after.

Answer (score 7):

Exporting the app as an .ipa and uploading via Application Loader 3.0 worked for me. (Restarting xcode, cleaning, and re-archiving did not.)

Answer (score 7):

I first tried to upload and got the "cannot verify client"-error.
Then i did a validate, which was successfull and then again a upload which also was successfull. No restart etc. needed.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. Clean build and deleting project caches worked.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and tried everything including Application Loader but still would not load into iTunes Connect. I'm running XCode 7.1.1 and OS X El Capitan.

I also have Avira (free version) installed and once I disable it, everything went through. Hope this helps someone.

Stackoverflow has been my savior and goto source for Obj C and now Swift!!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for all night. Got  ☕️ but didn't work.

Solved my problem only with:

1. Switching lan to wifi connection
2. Uploading App by Application Loader
3. Wasn't useful but i saw than in Xcode uploading start works as well after connection switching, so maybe was a connection my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clean project not work with me in XCode 7.2. But I solve the problem by export Archive and using Application Loader.

Step:

1. Archive you build.
2. In Organizer: Chose your archive.
3. Export "Save for iOS App Store Deployment".
4. Open Application Loader (Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader: Download it if you don't have).
5. Select "Deliver your App" -> Select your exported ipa.
6. Upload.

=> Done

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem since Xcode 7.1 (for more than a month). I did everything I could trying to solve this: restart Xcode, clean project, clean build folder, build with a device connected, reinstall Xcode multiple times, even formatting the whole disk and starting from scratch. None of this worked.

During this time my colleague was always able to upload the very same builds to App Store without any problem.

**Curiously, what solved this problem for me was disconnecting my non-Apple wireless mouse.**

I found this out when I tried to submit an app from my home computer and got the same error. I disconnected the mouse dongle, tried again and it went through.

I've verified this three times both on my home (MacBook Pro 2013) and work computer (Mac Mini 2014).

This leads me to believe that during the app submission process Apple may check if your environment is purely made by Apple or not, and may block your submission based on that. This would explain the "Cannot verify client" message.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: I got this error when my startdisk was almost full (less than a few hundred MB left).

Cleaning up some space and re-submitting resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing the same problem. Tried a number of the suggestions above. Ended up using the Application Uploader instead.

Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader

Answer (score 1):

From the rest of the answers it seems that a lot of different things "resolve" this issue. Here are the particulars of what solved it for me:

1. The iPad had to be plugged in.
2. The iPad had to be **signed in** (i.e. not locked).

After I satisfied those two conditions, it validates and uploads reliably. If either one isn't done, I am not able to validate or upload to iTunesConnect and I get the `Cannot verify client (3000)` error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Application Loader to upload your build and solve it!

Answer (score 0):

- [Download Provisiononing Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/obtain_certificates_and_provisioning_profiles.html) of app on Apple Developer,
- Quit and restart Xcode,
- Run Provisiononing Profiles by Xcode,
- Open app again,
- In  General -> get "fix" at Identity.

You can  Archive and  Upload to Apple Store

Answer (score 0):

When it fails two times in a row, choosing "Validate" and after that "Upload to App Store" does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the things here, but what finally did it for me was using the Application Loader instead of trying to upload my app from the Organizer.

Once I did it from the Application Loader I got an error message related to this: [ITMS-90535 Unable to publish iOS app with latest Google Signin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk), which was the real cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. I remade the app with "App Store" provisioning profile. Earlier it was "Ad-hoc" provisioning profile.
2. I submitted the app from "Application Loader" instead of traditional "Organizer".

Above two steps enabled me to submit the app to iTunes Connect for beta testing also.
There is always an element for surprise whenever apple releases an updated XCode.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few things, this is what worked for me:

- Just before uploading your executable, validate it, you then have a modal where you get to pick your binary. On the right, there's the name of the provisioning profile used. There's an arrow next to it.
- Click on the arrow which opens the finder to the location of the provisioning profile.
- Delete this file.
- Restart XCode
- Clean
- Rebuild/Archive
- Upload