# Cannot verify client 3000

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode7

I am using `xcode 7.1` and trying to upload my app to the app store directly through xcode. While uploading I am getting a weird error:-

> cannot verify client 3000

Note:- I recently made changes in the accounts (xcode preference section). Is this related to my error?

I also restart the xcode but issue still there?

I already checked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313393/getting-cannot-verify-client-3000-when-trying-to-upload-archive-from-xcode), but they say restart your xcode. But this does not solve my problem.

Comment: see this link may be helps you https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6740

Comment: Yep! Now I will try with Application Loader.

Comment: both are same , its your luck try once

Comment: I re-installed the xcode. Now error goes away. Now the build is not showing up at iTunes connect. Strange!

Comment: ok , very happy , in itunes conncet need to wait for some time

Comment: Give it another try and it will work like a charm. :)

Comment: Report: this happened to me. I very simply tried again, and it was fine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For my case,I got this error after selecting "Generic iOS Device" when archiving, however i plugged in my iPhone and selected it, then archived, I got no errors this time.(I also cleaned both Shift+cmd+k and Shift+alt+cmd+k before archiving)

Comment: Thanks @HussoM. I re-install xcode7.1 and it solve my problem.

Comment: I got same error, but second trying got no errors with same archive

Comment: Same here across multiple days: with the archive I made using Generic iOS Device, I got cannot verify client (as well as unauthorised to use service) errors from xcode 7.2 for 3 days straight. I eventually tried connecting my iphone and making a new archive from that, and boom it worked fine

Answer (score 23):

I encountered the same issue the first time I tried to submit to app store with the target on my device.

What worked for me:
I retried a couple of minutes later without changing a thing and everything went smooth.

Comment: That may be network glitch on your side at that time.

Comment: [pkc456](http://stackoverflow.com/users/988169/pkc456) that may be true but the issue is the same and I wanted to help other people which encountering the same problem to find a solution.

Comment: It looks like there are just too many of us trying to upload the apps to iTunes, Apple server can not keep up sometimes.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. In other words this is an error on Apple's end.

Comment: Might have to wait a couple hours even (I re-tried in the morning simply hitting the "upload" button again), but this indeed does the trick.

Comment: I agree that this is really the solution  ... it's a transient problem and you just have to try again.

Comment: That's right, I haven't changed anything either and after a few minutes it worked normally!

Answer (score 15):

This is temporary apple server bug. Try it again OR Retry after some time it will fix the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to reinstall Xcode. Just wait a few minutes and try again and it will work.

Comment: If this is the case, then what is the root cause of first time failure? It means there is some loop hope in the xcode which causes error sometime. Is it? If no, then why it will work on second time?

Comment: It might be either a network glitch from my end or Apple's servers. I ran into this problem 3 times this past week and the solution was just to wait a few minutes.

Comment: It's an issue on Apple's end

Answer (score 10):

I tried :

- waiting days,
- restarting,
- deleting the developer account in
  preferences,
- submitting archives from a connected device,
- submitting
  archives from a iOS generic device.

Nothing worked.

I needed to:

- create an archive (it was from a connected device),
- in the organiser window select the export button (on the right hand side underneath the "Upload to App Store" button.
- Select that the export is for app store distribution.
- Wait.
- Take a note of the location the .ipa file is saved to.
- Go back to Xcode, then select the menu item Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader.
- Select Deliver Your App, and select choose.
- Navigate to your .ipa file noted above.
- Select next, wait, next, check for any error message, send.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 8):

I got this error while uploading my distribution archive to App Store with selecting Distribution provisioning profile scheme -> Product -> Archive -> Upload to App Store. The error is based on I chose my real iphone device in Xcode by mistake. You need to choose "Generic iOS Device" and repeat same steps as I mentioned before.

Comment: In xcode 7.1, there is two different options:- Build only device(Generic iOS device) and Device. What is the difference between these two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287929/what-is-generic-ios-device-in-xcode-7-1-run-destinations-list    @pkc456

Comment: If I try to archive by using my own iPhone I have a certificate error I was not able to solve. Conversely if I archive by pointing to the generic device, the archiving goes find but, of course, I still get error 3000 when I try to upload the binary for Xcode. As for other users, submission from the Application Loader works fine.

Answer (score 5):

You have to plug in your iPhone to your Mac and try to upload to AppStore again.

Comment: I just plugged device and pressed "Upload to AppStore" button again.

Comment: I think with XCode 7 and bitcode ability, having a device plugged in will build the archive for that particular device. Selecting Generic iOS Device should build for all targeted devices

Comment: Of course you can build for "Generic iOS device" but you cannot do upload to AppStore if your device does not plugged in :(

Comment: @Vlad, I upload the build to app store without plugging in my device. So build with Generic iOS device can also results into the app store submission.

Comment: @pck456 You know, it seems device plugging is requied only once, just after XCode upgrade while first upload.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is **simply wrong**.  The problem does not relate to this.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, validating the archive before uploading fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 7.1, I could only make a successful build without bitcode. Try it out if everything else fails.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by exporting ("export" in xcode archive organizer -> "to iOS App Store") and using the Application Loader instead of xcode to submit.

Comment: Yep, application loader is better because it gives you detailed explanation of error.

Answer (score 1):

It is recurring. Seems to me like an internal error with apples identification service or so.

My definite solution: 
Get yourself a cup of tea and try it again.

You can, of course, do some voodoo or change the target device or something, but re-trying after a while will do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
I did the below steps:
Step 1: Select Code Signing Identity for "Release"
Step 2 : Select Distribution profile

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Application Loader instead and it worked well. Maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem since Xcode 7.1 (for more than a month). I did everything I could trying to solve this: restart Xcode, clean project, clean build folder, build with a device connected, reinstall Xcode multiple times, even formatting the whole disk and starting from scratch. None of this worked.

During this time my colleague was always able to upload the very same builds to App Store without any problem.

**Curiously, what solved this problem for me was disconnecting my non-Apple wireless mouse.**

I found this out when I tried to submit an app from my home computer and got the same error. I disconnected the mouse dongle, tried again and it went through.

I've verified this three times both on my home (MacBook Pro 2013) and work computer (Mac Mini 2014).

This leads me to believe that during the app submission process Apple may check if your environment is purely made by Apple or not, and may block your submission based on that. This would explain the "Cannot verify client" message.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

1. Delete the Archive that failed during upload.
2. Clean the solution.
3. Rebuild the solution.
4. Archive the it.
5. Go to Xcode's Organizer, then Validate (this should be 'Successful').
6. Upload the build.