# Binary from Xcode 7.0.1 not uploading due to Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key from advertiser framework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, binary, startapp

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to upload update on my game from Xcode 7.0.1 but I am getting this error shown in image. I have been to advertiser web page and I have made alterations as recommended. 1. Bitcoin-No 2. added this to info.plist
NSAppTransportSecurity-NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.

I am still getting same error, any idea what else can be done.

[image: info.plist image here. No key listed. still getting same error. Am I missing something in this list.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key)

Answer (score 1):

This might help [ITMS-90535 Unable to publish iOS app with latest Google Signin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk)

Find `CFBundleExecutable` key , remove the offending keys

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it with your helps. For the benefit of others I am loading image of info.plist from subproject. Remember this is not main project info.plist
I did following changes.....
1).remove ExecutableFile - StartApp(compare images).
2).change Bundle OS Type Code - BNDL(in subproject info.plist)
3).change bitCoin - No (in target)

This is my after image.(This info.plist worked)
[image]