# ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. "

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8, testflight

I am using apple's Test flight for delivering app to client for testing. I'm facing this error

> ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at
>   'Payload/MyAppName.app/GooglePlus.bundle' does not contain a bundle
>   executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an
>   executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its
>   Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is
>   part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of
>   the framework for an update to address this issue."

Tried every solution suggested in google like removing `CFBundleExecutable` key and changing `CFBundlePackageType BNDL`.When I run the project later in device its showing error as

> "missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its info.plist"

Here's the screenshot
[my info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HsYH.png)

Help me out soon with a valid solution.

Comment: remove the CFBundleExecutable key in the plist

Comment: When I have done the same I'm getting an error saying "Application loader is unable to load your package.                                                                      
  You must supply CFBundleIdentifier for this request "  ..Have any1 faced the same issue anytime while loading with Application loader

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm having this problem, too.  Any update?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk?noredirect=1#comment111905180_32622899

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-90535 Unable to publish iOS app with latest Google Signin SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622899/itms-90535-unable-to-publish-ios-app-with-latest-google-signin-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, with Xcode 11.5, and found the [solution](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70503) in [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/)
its Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally tried to submit a build to the Appstore from Xcode 10.2 beta 3.  When I realized the error and re-archived and re-submitted using the release version of Xcode (10.1), everything worked properly...